# Show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^x}=\ln2$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity

Prove $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{n-1}}{{n}^{x}}=\ln2.$$

---

Of course  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{n-1}}{{n}}=\ln2,$$
but we can not use the **Proposition** :

**If a sequence of functions that are continuous on a set converges uniformly on that set ,then the limit function is continuous on the set.**
because for $\forall\delta >0$,we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{n-1}}{{n}^{x}} $converges on$\left(1-\delta ,1+\delta  \right), $but nonuniformly .

---

In fact ,for every ${x}^{'},{x}^{"}\in \left(1,1+\delta  \right)，$in other words $\left| {x}^{'}-{x}^{"}\right|<\delta  $,fixing  the point $ {x}^{'}, $let ${x}^{"}\rightarrow {1}^{+},$we can get paradox:$$1\geq |\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{n-1}}{{n}^{{x}^{'}}}-(+\infty)|=+\infty>1.$$
So $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{n-1}}{{n}^{x}}$ converge nonuniformly on $\left(1-\delta  ,1+\delta  \right)$.

---

My question is how can we get $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{n-1}}{{n}^{x}}=\ln2.$

Comment: Please: Write $\ln2$, not $ln2$.  It is coded as \ln 2.  The backslash results in proper spcing in things like $2\ln3$ and in non-italicization of $\ln$.  Some other aspects of your way of writing MathJax code are appalling; they look as if they came from one those web-based applications supposedly intended to help with MathJax. I've cleaned it up somewhat.

Answer (score 4):

Let

$$f_N(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^x},\quad R_N(x) = \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^x}.$$

It is clear that for every $N$ you have $\lim_{x\to 1} f_N(x) = f_N(1)$. It remains to find a bound on

$$\lvert R_N(x)\rvert.$$

The fact that the series is alternating should help with that. (And that shows that actually the convergence of the series is uniform on $(1-\delta,1+\delta)$ for $0 < \delta < 1$.)

> Namely, for $x > 0$, we have $\frac{1}{n^x} > \frac{1}{(n+1)^x}$, and thus by Leibniz' criterion for alternating series, it follows that $$\lvert R_N(x)\rvert = \left\lvert \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(N+1+k)^x}\right\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{(N+1)^x}.$$ Since $x \mapsto \frac{1}{(N+1)^x}$ is monotonically decreasing on $(0,+\infty)$ for every $N\in\mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, we thus have $$\lvert R_N(x)\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{(N+1)^x} \leqslant \frac{1}{(N+1)^{1-\delta}}$$ for all $N$ and $x \geqslant 1-\delta$. It follows that the convergence of $f_N$ is uniform on every $[1-\delta,+\infty)$ for $0 < \delta < 1$. Thus the proposition cited in the question *can* be used.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{n-1}}{{n}^{x}}$ converge nonuniformly on $\left(1-\delta  ,1+\delta  \right)$.why @Daniel Fischer get the convergence of the series is uniform on $\left(1-\delta  ,1+\delta  \right).$I can't understand this.

Comment: Why do you think the convergence is not uniform? The convergence is not absolute (for $x \leqslant 1$), so the Weierstraß test fails. Yet, the convergence is uniform, since you can find a _uniform_ bound on $\lvert R_N(x)\rvert$ on $(1-\delta,1+\delta)$ as long as $0 < \delta < 1$.

Comment: In fact ,for every ${x}^{'},{x}^{"}\in \left(1,1+\delta  \right)，$in other words $\left| {x}^{'}-{x}^{"}\right|<\delta  $,fixing  the point $ {x}^{'}, $let ${x}^{"}\rightarrow {1}^{+},$we can get paradox:$$1\geq |\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{n-1}}{{n}^{{x}^{'}}}-(+\infty)|=+\infty>1.$$
So $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{n-1}}{{n}^{x}}$ converge nonuniformly on $\left(1-\delta  ,1+\delta  \right)$.

Comment: I don't see where you take the $+\infty$ from there.

Comment: Absolutely,your conclusion is not correct.$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}=+\infty.$

Comment: @Jay It is. Somewhere your reasoning went astray, and I'm trying to figure out where. Should I fill in the details I left out so far before we explore that further, or shall we explore first?

Comment: I am so tired, I think  I will go to sleep .

Comment: I've added the proof of uniform convergence, you can look at it when you're less tired.

Comment: I have made a big mistake, mistook$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{n-1}}{{n}^{x}} $for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{{n}^{x}}$ in my mind.We may use The Dirichlet test for uniform convergence to solve this question.

Answer (score 1):

You may observe that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{n-1}}{{n}^{x}}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}\int_0^\infty\frac{u^{x-1}}{e^u+1} \mathrm{d}u, \quad x>1.
$$
Letting $ x \rightarrow 1^+$ gives
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^+}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{{(-1)}^{n-1}}{{n}^{x}}=\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{e^u+1} \mathrm{d}u=\ln 2 .
$$

Comment: Do you konw $x\rightarrow {1}^{+}$ is different from $x\rightarrow {1}?$

Comment: @Jay I realize that I did not fully understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\lim_{x\ \to\ 1}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}%
{\pars{-1}^{n - 1} \over n^{x}}}
=-\lim_{x\ \to\ 1}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n^{x}}
=-\lim_{x\ \to\ 1}{\rm Li}_{x}\pars{-1}=-\,{\rm Li}_{1}\pars{-1}
\\[3mm]&=-\braces{-\ln\pars{1 - \bracks{-1}}}
=\color{#66f}{\Large\ln\pars{2}} \approx {\tt 0.6931}
\end{align}