# To Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k}\right).$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> **Prove That**  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k}\right).$

**My Approach** I was solving:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n}=
\left(1+\frac 1 3 + \frac 1 5 +\ldots \right)-\left(\frac 1 2 + \frac 1 4 +\ldots 
\right)
 =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n-1}- \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n}$$
Searching On Mathstack i found [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/407862/501526)

I know that $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n}$ = $\ln2$ But i don't know how to prove it using this method.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356517/what-is-the-correct-radius-of-convergence-for-ln1x

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890207/show-that-lim-x-rightarrow-1-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1n-1nx-ln2?rq=1

Comment: @user236182 i know that brother ,that's why i said  I know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$$\frac{1}{2n-1}$ - $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$$\frac{1}{2n}$

Comment: Try typing \ln 2 instead of ln 2.

Comment: You will get $\ln 2$ instead of ln 2.

Comment: The equality isn't correct: Neither of the two sums converges.

Comment: @Travis In a previously asked question i saw this equality.I am gonna search it again and post the link

Comment: @travis  See this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/407862/501526

Comment: @GuyFsone I know that question ,you can see this as a follow up. this is about the method

Comment: Then this edit is a duplicate

Answer (score 6):

Both series$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n-1}\text{ and }\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n}$$diverge. Therefore, the equality$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n-1}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n}=\ln2$$makes no sense.

---

**Note:** What I wrote was an answer to the problem of proving that$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n-1}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n}=\ln2.$$The question was edited afterwards.

Comment: I'm supposing the OP meant subtraction term by term.

Comment: Sir i got the equality from this post  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/407862/501526

Comment: @MohanSharma What is asserted in that post is that$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1 {2k-1}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1 {2k}\right)=\ln2.$$This is **not** what you wrote.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sir i have edited my question

Comment: @MohanSharma as it stands now, it makes no sense.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sir i have made my best efforts in the improvement of the question . Still if it does'nt makes sense please suggest an edit

Comment: @MohanSharma State that what ypu want to prove is that$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k}\right)=\ln2.$$

Comment: @MohanSharma Read my answer, which extends José Carlos' answer.

Comment: Then the current  edit is a duplicate

Comment: @GuyFsone The current edit makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you're confusing this with,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac 1 {2n-1} - \frac 1 {2n}\right)$$

Note that both $\sum \frac 1 {2n-1}$ and $\sum \frac 1 {2n}$ are divergent from the divergence of the harmonic series, so to "split up" the summand does not make mathematical sense.

However, to say,

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \left(\sum_{n=1}^k \frac 1 {2n-1} - \sum_{n=1}^k \frac 1 {2n}\right)$$

Is fine. It is however not equivalent to what you write. Note that just as we can't split the above sum using additivity as both sums diverge, we cannot split the above limit using additivity as both terms increase without bound.

Comment: Yes brother i got that ,so i have edited my question

Answer (score 2):

*As said in the other answer, it makes no sense to split the convergent sum into two divergent sums.*

However, we can look at what happens for partial sums.

Notice that $\quad -\dfrac 1{2k}=\dfrac 1{2k}-\dfrac 1k\quad$ so

$\begin{align}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{2N}\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}n
&=\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\left(\dfrac 1{2n-1}-\dfrac 1{2n}\right)
=\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\left(\dfrac 1{2n}+\dfrac 1{2n-1}-\dfrac 1{n}\right)\\\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{2N} \dfrac 1n-\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\dfrac 1n
=\sum\limits_{n=N+1}^{2N}\dfrac 1n=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\dfrac 1{n+N}\\\\
&=\dfrac 1N\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\dfrac 1{1+\frac nN}\xrightarrow{\text{Riemann sum}}\int_0^1\dfrac{dt}{1+t}=\ln(2)\end{align}$

Comment: This answer though doesn't address the really important point, imo, of this question, which is rearranging finite sums created from conditionally convergent series. Read José Carlos answer or my answer...and your very second equallity is unjustified, of course, as it only reflects **your own** choice of rearranging...

Comment: @DonAntonio if you rearrange (for instance the example in your answer) you won't get the partial sum from $n=1..2N$ described here (some terms will be missing). There is nothing ambiguous in my method, I take the partial sum and show it has a limit. It is fine to show OP that rearrangement of **infinite** semi-convergent sums is forbidden, but that doesn't apply to partial sums which by definition are finite.

Comment: You *did adopt* the unwritten and unagreed convention that the sum in the question is the same as a termwise substraction: it is clearly written that way in the first equality with the sums...! I **agree** that's ONE WAY to arrange the original difference of sums in the question...but there are other arrangements, of course. Thus, of course my example won't fit what **you describe** here. It won't fit **also** what the OP, and others, thought it should fit...and from here the ambiguity of your method, as with other answers.

Comment: @DonAntonio No, I'm just applying definition of a semi-convergent series. The series of term $(-1)^n/n$ is semi-convergent if the partial sum converge and the series is not absolutely convergent. So, I write the partial sum, it is finite so I arrange however I want the 2N terms (I can do that, there are finitely many terms, nothing unagreed) and it has a limit. This is not a choice or whatever, this is mathematics. Reading your prose it seems you are the one who is confused about semi-convergent series.

Comment: @zv **Exactly my point** ! You "arrange it however you want...". That the limit is different with different arrangements is, I believe, beyond any reasonable discussion: just see the example in my answer! The fact that you arrange as you **a conditional convergent sum** (or its finite partial sum and then pass to the limit) makes all the difference. Now, your arrangement of a finite sum of a *convergent series* is fine but, as you can see, you **do not get to decide** in what order to take the different signed summands...or else that's already a choice and different ones give different results

Comment: I stop here, because you do not seem to KNOW what a partial sum is.

Comment: @zw I understand your frustration.

Answer (score 1):

It may all depend on the meaning you give to things...and on the way you write things that are agreed by almost everybody else.

If we take **a finite** sum of real numbers then we can use commutativity, associativity and etc. with, so we could *agree that*

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k-1}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k}=\left(1+\frac13+\ldots+\frac1{2n-1}\right)-\left(\frac12+\frac14+\ldots+\frac1{2n}\right)=$$

$$=1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\ldots+\frac1{2n-1}-\frac1{2n} (**)$$

and then indeed we get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k-1}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\ldots+\frac1{2n-1}-\frac1{2n}\right)=\log2$$

since we have the power series

$$\log(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}n$$

which is valid for $\;|x|\le1\;$ (why?), and thus with $\;x=1\;$ we get the above result.

**Observe though** that we could have *agreed* in $\;(**)\;$ that, for example:

$$\left(1+\frac13+\ldots+\frac1{2n-1}\right)-\left(\frac12+\frac14+\ldots+\frac1{2n}\right)=$$

$$=1-\frac12-\frac14+\frac13-\frac16-\frac18+\frac15-\ldots=\frac12\log2$$
and we get something different! This can happen, and *actually does happen*, when we rearrange the terms of a conditionally convergent series, as the alteranting harmonic series is, which you can rearrange it to get **any sum you want**, up to and including $\;\pm\infty\;$ !

You may want to read about "Riemann Theorem" in series. Google it...it is fascinating.

Comment: After all the edits i made, Is my question still a duplicate?

Comment: Thanks For answering the actual question

Comment: @MohanSharma Nop, not quite. José Carlos **did actually answer your actual question** . I only extended explanations on the case you want. As you wrote it, it **really makes no sense** since, as written above, we can actually rearrange the terms of those two sums and make it converge to whatever we want...or even to diverge to $\;\pm\infty\;$ .Thus, it seems to be that in your question you linked to another question...and imo it **still is wrong** if you add $\;\lim_{n\to\infty}\;$ , since it still isn't clear what arrange you want!

Comment: I think this is misleading. Sure, one has to be careful rearranging the infinite series. But in the OP we have a limit of a finite sum, and that's unambiguously equal to $\log2$. You may check Wolfram Alpha or see it like $H_{2n}-H_n=\log(2n)-\log n+o(1)=\log2+o(1)$. And anyway, for finite $n$, it's the limit of $\sum_{k=1}^n\left (\frac1{2k-1}-\frac1{2k}\right) $, which is exclusively the alternating harmonic series.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva Read my answer if you want: that is *completely ambiguous* as there is no real reason to rearrange that finite sum with alternating signs...why?! Why not $\;1-\frac12-\frac14+\frac13-\frac16-\frac18+\frac15-\ldots\;$ ? Checking WA for these subtle yet important questions can be a dangerous thing: WA has lots of bugs and mistakes and several things. Your last sentence is completely unjustified, thus.

Comment: Take the sequence in the OP. Adding to it $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k}$ we get $H_{2n}-H_n$, don't we?

Comment: @Vin It all depends: what does $\;H_{2n}-H_n\;$ **means**? It means, as usually **agreed**, the alternating series? Then yes...but not otherwise! Why won't that difference of finite sums be understood as I write at the end of my answer ?! That's why I began my answer with "it all **depends** on what we have agreed on" ...

Comment: Why can't we see it just as the difference of two harmonic numbers? That converges to $\log2$.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva Yes, we can...and we can **even agree on that** . But unless there's a priori agreement, **anyone can decide how to rearrange** that...and each arrangement will produce a different result, as shown in my answer ! That diffrerence is not **necessarily** a termwise difference: why would it be ?! It will be so *if we agree* on that...

Comment: I understand what you mean, but that has to do with *series* not *partial sums*. The limit in the OP *is* $\log 2$, and reading @JoséCarlosSantos ' comments I see he agrees, contrary to what you seem to suggest. Fair enough though, I'm not here for a big discussion.

Comment: You may also look at the answers to the question of which the OP is a duplicate, to convince yourself

Comment: @VincenzoOliva Sometimes is useless to try to explain some things to certain people. I won't continue with this...and hopefully mathematics is not turning into a sloppy discipline in many places.

Comment: Do not worry, it is not. :)