# Proving Cauchy sequence and its convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

As I am having trouble in concluding the question, please look at this also: For a sequence $$1 - \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3}+\cdots +\frac{(−1)^{n−1}}{n} \\
\text{Then}\\
|s_n−s_m| = \left|\frac{(−1)^{m−1}}{m} +\frac{(−1)^{m}}{m+1} +\cdots+\frac{(−1)^{n−1}}{n}\right| \\
\leq | \sum_{k=m}^{n} \frac{(−1)^{k−1}}{k} | \\
\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(−1)^{k−1}}{k} $$
Since the sequence is monotonically increasing
$$\leq\log2,$$ so can we end the question by saying:
For each $\epsilon\geq\log2≥0$, there exists a positive integer  $M\geq\epsilon$  such that for $n,m\geq M$, we have that $|s_n−s_m|\leq\epsilon$, and therefore it is convergent. But I came to know that my proof does not work for any epsilon i e. Less then log2 , please help me to correct it.

Comment: By the first inequality, you should have $|(-1)^{k-1}|=1$ in the numerator.

Comment: By using Approach0, I found that your problem is discussed in this thread:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2606035/to-prove-lim-n-to-infty-left-sum-k-1n-frac12k-1-sum-k-1n-fra?noredirect=1